# Google Cloud Endpoints and javascript client stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-endpoints

We have two separate App Engine projects and today both of those stopped working with Google Cloud Endpoints. Using the Api Explorer works fine. The first call to discovery works and it returns all the available commands. Using the client however fails for example "gapi.client.od.process.custom.list()" returns:

```
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
    ]
},
"id": "gapiRpc"
```

Same thing happens while using **Google's own APIs**: "gapi.client.plus.people.get({"userId": "me"})"

We are using same flow as in the [Google documents](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_js).

Yesterday everything worked fine. Did Google change something in it's client.js? Where would be the right place to start investigating this kind of error?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136)

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({"userId":"me"});
request.B.apiVersion = "v1";
request.execute(...)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Yes that was actually me :) They are rolling back the library.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue with the JavaScript client Google is working on it.

[URGENT - Google Drive SDK JavaScript 404 Error on any method](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136)